# cartodb - toggle display and control multiple time-series maps on the same tile layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, cartodb

I have five animated heat map time series generated in carto. I need to display them one by one when a button is clicked in my webpage.

Here is a screenshot of my page
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAkpq.png)

The idea is that only the relevant time series map should display for the button clicked.

I managed to get heat-maps to load on button click with below method, but it doesn't clear the previously active layer and also the time-series control (play/pause) seem to only apply to the initial layer.

```
 var LayerActions = {

 button1: function(){
   var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
   cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl, layerOptions).addTo(map);            
   return true;  
   },

   button2: function(){
   cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl2, layerOptions).addTo(map);
   return true;
   }
```

Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

yajith

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating and removing layers, I recommend hiding and showing them as explained [in this working example](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/10506396).

First, you have to create a `createSelector` function which accepts `layers` as the argument, and activates when clicking. Thus showing and hiding your layers as needed. Secondly, create a visualization or [a layer with sublayers](http://jsfiddle.net/jsanz/rkp6svf7/) and invoke the previous function.